# Selecting multiple rows using WHERE function

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, where-clause

I am trying to search for multiple rows within a database using the PDO handler, using the WHERE function to search for multiple row/variables. I can successful search for individual items using just one name variable, however I was hoping to search for multiple.
This is what I've tried but its not working:

`$result=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM hire WHERE name='item1', 'item2", 'item3');`

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You are in need of a [WHERE...IN clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to choose from a set of values you can use the `IN` selector, like this:

```
$result=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM hire WHERE name IN('item1', 'item2', 'item3')");
```